# Using redis in an Express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

I want to simply be able to store a value in a key in one route

```
/api/foo?redisKey="1" (set value for id=1)
```

then I want to get the value in another route.

```
/api/bar?redisKey="1" (get value for id=1)
```

However, redis is async so you have to wait for it to connect

```
client.on('connect', function() {
    //perform redis operations
});
```

I'm not sure how to synchronize this in my router.

Comment: What redis client are you using? [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) or [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis)? Usually you don't need to wait for the connection to be established, as it's built into the client library not to dispatch commands until a connection is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you're using [redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) for your client library.

In your express route file, you do not want to create the connection during each request. Instead you will instantiate your redis client outside of the express middleware function, and use it during requests.

Here's a sample app:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// GET request
// example: curl "localhost:3000/api/foo?redisKey=1"
app.get('/api/foo', function (req, res) {
  var redisKey = req.query.redisKey

  client.get(redisKey, function (err, reply) {
    if(err){ res.status(400).send(err.getMessage()); return; }
    res.status(200).send(reply.toString())
  });
})

// for setting, use POST request
// example: curl -X POST "localhost:3000/api/foo?redisKey=1&redisValue=helloWorld"
app.post('/api/foo', function(req, res){
  var redisKey = req.query.redisKey,
      redisValue = req.query.redisValue
      // assuming value is also a string in URL query string

  client.set(redisKey, redisValue, function (err, reply){
    res.status(200).send(reply.toString())
  });
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: I thought there would be a chance that client.get would be called before the client is actually connected. I guess I was overthinking it.

Comment: it is in fact possible, however thanks to the awesome nodejs community we don't have to worry about it with the 2 main npm pkgs

Comment: nice. what 2 main npm pkgs?

Comment: same as I mentioned in my 1st comment above